# Return the results of a function to HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying return the results of a function called LineItemCalc() into a HTML table located within a div (id = BurgerOrder) with the following layout

### Order Group Burger Item        | Price

```
        Pepperoni          | 0.75
        Tomatoes           | 0.7
        Pineapple          | 1
```

### Chosen Toppings                    | 2.45

```
        Beef Brisket & Chunks  | 3.75
```

### Chosen Meat                    | 3.75

```
        Chedder                | 1.75
```

### Chosen Cheese                      | 1.75

```
        Dijonnaise             | 1.75
        Honey BBQ Sauce        | 1.8
```

### Chosen Sauce                       | 3.55

```
        Spiced Sesame Buns     | 1
```

### Chosen Bread                       | 1

### Subtotal                       | 25

At the moment it returns the result as a console.log when the user enter orderstage 6 and clicks on the button, however I need to show it as a HTML table

Any help would be appreciated

I have tried using push method however it appends to the existing array and gives me the following output:

```
let customer-burger = ["Pepperoni", 0.75,"Tomatoes",0.7,"Pineapple", 1.00]
```

however my intent was

```
let customer-burger = [{"Chosen Item", "Chosen Item Price"},{"Pepperoni", 0.75},{"Tomatoes",0.7},{"Pineapple", 1.00}]
```

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Burger Build</title>
<link href="Burger-Build.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alfa+Slab+One|Bangers|Lobster|Permanent+Marker" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>


    <div class="modal-bb">  <!-- Container for modal-box -->
        <div class="modal-bb-contents"> <!-- modal-box -->
            <div class = "button-container">
                <p class="expander-toggle" id="burger-toggle" onClick="burgerOptionsToggle()">+</p>
                <button id="heading-button">Start Creating Your burger</button>             
            </div>

            <div class="ingre-chkbox" id="burger-options">
            </div>
            <div id="BurgerOrder">
            </div>
            <div>
            <button id="submit-button" onClick="headingTitle();">Click to Start</button>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>

<script src="burger-build.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
//creation arrays to store checkbox options
let ChosenToppings = [];
let ChosenMeats = [];   
let ChosenCheese = [];
let ChosenSauce = [];
let ChosenBread = [];

let orderstage = 1;
 //Stage of ordering process
                    //1: Burger Topping
                    //2: Meat Patty
                    //3: Cheese
                    //4: Sauce
                    //5: Bread

//stage 1
const AvailableToppings = [
                        {Name: "No Additional Toppings",ExtraPrice: 0.00},
                        {Name: "Pepperoni",ExtraPrice: 0.75},
                        {Name: "Tomatoes", ExtraPrice: 0.70},
                        {Name: "Anchovies", ExtraPrice: 0.60},
                        {Name: "Mushroom", ExtraPrice: 0.50},
                        {Name: "Gerkins", ExtraPrice: 0.80},
                        {Name: "Pineapple", ExtraPrice: 1.00},
                        {Name: "Turkey Ham", ExtraPrice: 1.00},
                        {Name: "Caramalised Onions", ExtraPrice: 1.50},
                        {Name: "Donner", ExtraPrice: 1.50},
                        {Name: "Jalapenos", ExtraPrice: 0.50}
                        ];

//stage 2
const AvailableMeats = [
                        {Name: "Beef Brisket & Chunks",ExtraPrice: 3.75},
                        {Name: "Chicken Fillet", ExtraPrice: 3.50},
                        {Name: "Crabmeat", ExtraPrice: 3.60},
                        {Name: "Chickpeas", ExtraPrice: 2.50},
                        ];

//Stage 3
const AvailableCheese = [
                        {Name: "No Cheese", ExtraPrice: 0.00},
                        {Name: "Chedder", ExtraPrice: 1.75},
                        {Name: "Brie", ExtraPrice: 1.70},
                        {Name: "Goat Cheese", ExtraPrice: 1.60},
                        {Name: "Smoked Gouda", ExtraPrice: 1.50},
                        {Name: "Monterey Jack", ExtraPrice: 1.5},
                        {Name: "Stilton", ExtraPrice: 3.00}
                        ]

//stage 4
const AvailableSauce = [
                        {Name: "No Sauce", ExtraPrice: 0.00},
                        {Name: "Dijonnaise", ExtraPrice: 1.75},
                        {Name: "Sriracha Mayo", ExtraPrice: 1.70},
                        {Name: "Classic Aioli", ExtraPrice: 1.60},
                        {Name: "Toasted Sesame Teriyaki Sauce", ExtraPrice: 1.50},
                        {Name: "Mole Poblano", ExtraPrice: 1.5},
                        {Name: "Honey BBQ Sauce", ExtraPrice: 1.80},
                        {Name: "Cheese Sauce", ExtraPrice: 1.80}
                        ]

//stage 5
const AvailableBread = [
                        {Name: "Ciabatta Roll", ExtraPrice: 0.75},
                        {Name: "English Muffin", ExtraPrice: 0.70},
                        {Name: "Brioche bun", ExtraPrice: 0.60},
                        {Name: "Onion Roll", ExtraPrice: 0.50},
                        {Name: "StroopWafel", ExtraPrice: 0.80},
                        {Name: "Spiced Sesame Buns", ExtraPrice: 1.00},
                        {Name: "Pretzel Roll", ExtraPrice: 1.00}
                        ]

function headingTitle(){
    var submitbtn = document.getElementById("submit-button")
    var headingbtn = document.getElementById("heading-button")

 if (orderstage == 1) {
        console.log("Heading Title - Stage:" + orderstage)
        submitbtn.innerHTML = "Submit toppings";
        headingbtn.innerHTML= "Choose Burger Toppings";
        burgerOptionsToggle();
        submitbtn.setAttribute("onClick", "submitToppings()");

} else if (orderstage == 2) {
        console.log("Heading Title - Stage:" + orderstage);
        submitbtn.innerHTML = "Submit Patty Options";
        headingbtn.innerHTML = "Choose Meat Patty";
        meatOptionsToggle();
        submitbtn.setAttribute("onClick", "submitToppings()");
} else if (orderstage == 3) {
        console.log("Heading Title - Stage:" + orderstage);
        submitbtn.innerHTML = "Submit Cheese Options";
        headingbtn.innerHTML = "Choose Cheese Options";
        cheeseOptionsToggle();
        submitbtn.setAttribute("onClick", "submitToppings()");
} else if (orderstage == 4) {
        console.log("Heading Title - Stage:" + orderstage);
        submitbtn.innerHTML = "Submit Sauce Options";
        headingbtn.innerHTML = "Choose Sauce Options";
        sauceOptionsToggle();
        submitbtn.setAttribute("onClick", "submitToppings()");
} else if (orderstage == 5) {
        console.log("Heading Title - Stage:" + orderstage);
        submitbtn.innerHTML = "Submit Burger Concoction";
        headingbtn.innerHTML = "Choose Bread Options";
        breadOptionsToggle();
        submitbtn.setAttribute("onClick", "submitToppings()");
} else if (orderstage == 6) {
        console.log("Heading Title - Stage:" + orderstage);
        submitbtn.setAttribute("onClick", "BurgerCalcs()");
        submitbtn.innerHTML = "Complete Burger Concoction";
        headingbtn.innerHTML = "You Burger Concoction";
}};

//Burger Options Toggle
function burgerOptionsToggle(){
var ingreChkboxes = document.getElementById('burger-options');

AvailableToppings.map((AvailableTopping, index) => {
  var Name = AvailableTopping.Name;
  var parentDiv = document.createElement('div');
  parentDiv.setAttribute('class', 'column');

  var Label = document.createElement('label');
  Label.setAttribute('for', Name);
  var Node = document.createTextNode(Name + " ");
  Label.appendChild(Node);

  var Input = document.createElement('input');
  Input.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
  Input.setAttribute('name', Name);

  parentDiv.appendChild(Label).appendChild(Input);

  ingreChkboxes.appendChild(parentDiv);
});
    }

//Meat Options Toggle
function meatOptionsToggle(){
var ingreChkboxes = document.getElementById('burger-options');

AvailableMeats.map((AvailableMeats, index) => {
  var Name = AvailableMeats.Name;
  var parentDiv = document.createElement('div');
  parentDiv.setAttribute('class', 'column');

  var Label = document.createElement('label');
  Label.setAttribute('for', Name);
  var Node = document.createTextNode(Name + " ");
  Label.appendChild(Node);

  var Input = document.createElement('input');
  Input.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
  Input.setAttribute('name', Name);

  parentDiv.appendChild(Label).appendChild(Input);

  ingreChkboxes.appendChild(parentDiv);
});
    }

//Cheese Options Toggle
function cheeseOptionsToggle(){
var ingreChkboxes = document.getElementById('burger-options');

AvailableCheese.map((AvailableCheese, index) => {
  var Name = AvailableCheese.Name;
  var parentDiv = document.createElement('div');
  parentDiv.setAttribute('class', 'column');

  var Label = document.createElement('label');
  Label.setAttribute('for', Name);
  var Node = document.createTextNode(Name + " ");
  Label.appendChild(Node);

  var Input = document.createElement('input');
  Input.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
  Input.setAttribute('name', Name);

  parentDiv.appendChild(Label).appendChild(Input);

  ingreChkboxes.appendChild(parentDiv);
});
    }

//Sauce Options Toggle
function sauceOptionsToggle(){
var ingreChkboxes = document.getElementById('burger-options');

AvailableSauce.map((AvailableSauce, index) => {
  var Name = AvailableSauce.Name;
  var parentDiv = document.createElement('div');
  parentDiv.setAttribute('class', 'column');

  var Label = document.createElement('label');
  Label.setAttribute('for', Name);
  var Node = document.createTextNode(Name + " ");
  Label.appendChild(Node);

  var Input = document.createElement('input');
  Input.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
  Input.setAttribute('name', Name);

  parentDiv.appendChild(Label).appendChild(Input);

  ingreChkboxes.appendChild(parentDiv);
});
    }

//Bread Options Toggle
function breadOptionsToggle(){
var ingreChkboxes = document.getElementById('burger-options');

AvailableBread.map((AvailableBread, index) => {
  var Name = AvailableBread.Name;
  var parentDiv = document.createElement('div');
  parentDiv.setAttribute('class', 'column');

  var Label = document.createElement('label');
  Label.setAttribute('for', Name);
  var Node = document.createTextNode(Name + " ");
  Label.appendChild(Node);

  var Input = document.createElement('input');
  Input.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
  Input.setAttribute('name', Name);

  parentDiv.appendChild(Label).appendChild(Input);

  ingreChkboxes.appendChild(parentDiv);
});
    }

//Add checkbox options to selective array
function submitToppings() {
    var burgerTopping = document.getElementById("burger-options")
    var options = document.querySelectorAll("#burger-options input[type=checkbox]");

    if (orderstage == 1) {

    options.forEach((option) => {
       if(option.checked) {
           ChosenToppings.push(option.getAttribute('name'));
       }
        //burgerTopping.style.display = "none";
    })
            orderstage++;
            console.log(orderstage);
            console.log(ChosenToppings);
            console.log("removeElementsByClass");
            removeElementsByClass("column");
} else if (orderstage == 2) {

    options.forEach((option) => {
       if(option.checked) {
           ChosenMeats.push(option.getAttribute('name'));
       }
        //burgerTopping.style.display = "none";
    })
            orderstage++;
            console.log(orderstage);
            console.log(ChosenMeats);
            console.log("removeElementsByClass");
            removeElementsByClass("column");
} else if (orderstage == 3) {

    options.forEach((option) => {
       if(option.checked) {
           ChosenCheese.push(option.getAttribute('name'));
       }
        //burgerTopping.style.display = "none";
    })
            orderstage++;
            console.log(orderstage);
            console.log(ChosenCheese);
            console.log("removeElementsByClass");
            removeElementsByClass("column");
} else if (orderstage == 4) {

    options.forEach((option) => {
       if(option.checked) {
           ChosenSauce.push(option.getAttribute('name'));
       }
        //burgerTopping.style.display = "none";
    })
            orderstage++;
            console.log(orderstage);
            console.log(ChosenSauce);
            console.log("removeElementsByClass");
            removeElementsByClass("column");
} else if (orderstage == 5) {

    options.forEach((option) => {
       if(option.checked) {
           ChosenBread.push(option.getAttribute('name'));
       }
        //burgerTopping.style.display = "none";
    })
            orderstage++;
            console.log(orderstage);
            console.log(ChosenBread);
            console.log("removeElementsByClass");
            removeElementsByClass("column");
}}

//Delete checkbox options
function removeElementsByClass(className){

    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
    while(elements.length > 0){
        elements[0].parentNode.removeChild(elements[0]);
    };
    headingTitle(orderstage);
}


function BurgerCalcs() {
    LineItemCalc('Chosen Toppings',ChosenToppings, AvailableToppings);
    LineItemCalc('Chosen Meat',ChosenMeats, AvailableMeats);
    LineItemCalc('Chosen Cheese',ChosenCheese, AvailableCheese);
    LineItemCalc('Chosen Sauce',ChosenSauce, AvailableSauce);
    LineItemCalc('Chosen Bread',ChosenBread, AvailableBread);
}

//Search the chosen array against a string value and return a name and extra price value
function LineItemCalc( Option, ChosenArray, AvailableArray) {
    let subtotal = 0.00;
    for (var ct=0; ct<ChosenArray.length; ct++) {
        let ctn = ChosenArray[ct];

            for (var i=0; i < AvailableArray.length; i++) {
                if (AvailableArray[i].Name === ctn) {
                                    console.log(AvailableArray[i].Name +" : £" + AvailableArray[i].ExtraPrice)
                                    subtotal = subtotal + AvailableArray[i].ExtraPrice;
                    }
                    }

        }
        console.log(Option + ": £" + subtotal)  
}
```

Comment: You should push the entire object to the array.  `customer-burger.push({"Chosen Item", "Chosen Item Price"})`

Comment: @Webber: How would I convert that to a HTML table?

Comment: You could use [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) or Array.forEach() for that and return a table row per item.

Comment: @Webber I tried tried however I keep getting an error. please confirm if this is correct for (var i=0; i < AvailableArray.length; i++) {
    if (AvailableArray[i].Name === ctn) {
         customerBurger.push({customerBurger:"Chosen Item", "Chosen Item Price"});
         console.log(AvailableArray[i].Name +" : £" + AvailableArray[i].ExtraPrice)
         customerBurger.push({"Chosen Item", "Chosen Item Price"})

Comment: It would be extremely helpful if you added what you've tried to your question. Also note that your question is very verbose, which makes it hard to find the relevant code. Could you update your question to be a simplified version of what you're trying to do? That way more people in the community can help out too.